# How to find constants in a function if the function and its derivative is given?

Tags: calculus, functions, derivatives, constants

If the function is : $$f(x) = (2x-b)^a$$ And it's derivative is: $$f'(x) = 24x^2-24x+6$$
Then find the value of $a$ and $b$

I tried by calculating the derivative of $f(x)$ which comes out to be: $$f'(x) = 2a(2x-b)^{a-1}$$ And then by equating the two  : $$24x^2-24x+6 = 2a(2x-b)^{a-1}$$

From now on I really don't know how to approach it, any kind of help would be appreciated .Thanks in advance.

Comment: Compute the derivative from f and identify the two expressions.

Comment: why not just integrate $f'(x)$? You get a cubic so isn't $a$ obvious? Then compare different terms to find $b$.

Comment: Based on your edit, LHS is a quadratic so what can $(a - 1)$ be?

Comment: Hint: The degree of a polynomial and the coefficients of a polynomial are unique.

Comment: The way I would do it - integrate and you get $f(x) = 8x^3 - 12x^2 + 6x + c$. So looking at the degree of the polynomial, $a = 3$. Now take coefficient of $x^2$ or $x$ in $(2x-b)^3$ to find $b$ and then finally validate you got everything right.

Answer (score 1):

Well, we compute:

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left(\left(\text{n}x-\text{b}\right)^\text{a}\right)=\text{a}\left(\text{n}x-\text{b}\right)^{\text{a}-1}\cdot\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left(\text{n}x-\text{b}\right)=$$
$$\text{a}\left(\text{n}x-\text{b}\right)^{\text{a}-1}\cdot\left(\text{n}\cdot\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x}\left(x\right)-\text{b}\cdot\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left(1\right)\right)=\text{a}\left(\text{n}x-\text{b}\right)^{\text{a}-1}\cdot\left(\text{n}\cdot1-\text{b}\cdot0\right)\tag1$$